# Why $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can't have proper subfields?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

From the notes I'm studying from I read that " $\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{F}_p$ has no proper subfield."

The rationale is: "assuming  $\mathbb{K}$ is a subfield of a finite field  $\mathbb{Z}_p= \mathbb{F}_p$, $p$ prime, then $\mathbb{K}$
must contain 0, and 1, and so all other elements of  $\mathbb{F}_p$ by the closure of  $\mathbb{K}$ under
addition. Therefore, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{F}_p$ contains no proper subfield"

But thinking about $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{0,1,2\}$

Isn't $\mathbb{Z}_3$ a proper subfield of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ since it contains 0, 1 and is closed under addition and multiplication?

Comment: No, it is **not** closed neither under addition ( $\;2+1=3\;$)  nor under multiplication ($\;2\cdot2=4\;$)

Comment: Yes but since $2+1 \equiv 0\pmod 3$ and $2\cdot2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ doesn't this close the operations inside the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ field?

Comment: You have to calculate $\mod 5$

Comment: Yes, got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a proper sub**set**, but it’s not a sub**field** at all: for example, $2^2=1$ in $\Bbb F_3$, and $2^2=4\ne 1$ in $\Bbb F_5$, so they don’t have the same operations. Similarly, $1+2=0$ in $\Bbb F_3$, but $1+2=3\ne 0$ in $\Bbb F_5$.

Comment: So you're saying that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ must be closed respect to $\pmod 5$ addition right? This is the rationale...

Comment: @Alessio: Yes. A subgroup of a group is a subset that is itself a group under the same operation; a subring of a ring is a subset that is itself a ring under the same operations; a subfield of a field is a subset that is itself a field under the same operations.

Comment: @AlessioMartorana Also, note that in $\Bbb Z_5$, $2+2+2=1$, but in $\Bbb Z_3$, $2+2+2=0$. The operations are very different.

Comment: Nitpick(?): I don't think there is a well-defined way to call $\Bbb{Z}_3$ a subset of $\Bbb{Z}_5$. Even though we denote elements of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ by $0,1,2,3,4$ they are properly residue classes, so in $\Bbb{Z}_5$ we have $0=\overline{0}=\{0,\pm5,\pm10,\ldots\}$, $1=\overline{1}=\{1,6,11,\ldots,-4,-9,\ldots\}$ et cetera, but in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ we have $0=\{0,\pm3,\pm6,\ldots\}$ and $1=\{1,4,7,\ldots,-2,-5,-8,\ldots\}$. In other words, the $1\in\Bbb{Z}_3$ is a different object from $1\in\Bbb{Z}_5$. I won't "forget" to use the bar until later, when my students have become familiar enough with this.

Comment: @Jyrki: I debated with myself and decided that what I wrote was probably going to be more helpful to the OP than a more careful statement, since (I think) it gets to the heart of the confusion. And after all, in practice we do often identify $\Bbb F_p$ with $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with suitably defined operations, so I'd say that there is at least a semi-standard sense in which the one is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Any proper subfield of $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ would have to be, in particular, a *sugbroup* of its additive group. But this is a group of order a prime $\;p\;$ , and as such it has no proper divisors, so by Lagrange's Theorem that's impossible.